# Renaming JSON field using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Say we have this JSON string:

```
const v = `{"foo":"bar"}`;
```

is there a way to configure parsing with JSON.parse so that a field gets renamed, for example capitalizing the field name:

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(v, captitalize);
console.log(parsed);  // => {Foo: "bar"}
```

or some way to transform the field names, depending on which field you are working with?

Comment: Why not capitalizing after parsing?

Comment: You only capitalized the first letter of the Key... presuming that by field you mean Key.

Comment: @vibhor1997a well using JSON libs in other languages, you can choose which source fields get parsed into which destination fields, there's more control. Capitalization was just an example, but I am looking for more configurability to turn the string into an object.

Comment: [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) *"If a reviver is specified, the **value** computed by parsing is transformed before being returned. "* - So that's what you were referring to I presume, but this only effects the **value** and not the **key**, and You're asking about the key.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *reviver* parameter to [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to modify objects as they're revived:

```js
const v = `{"foo":"bar"}`;
const result = JSON.parse(v, (name, value) => {
  if (value && typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value)) {
    // It's a non-null, non-array object, create a replacement with the keys initially-capped
    const newValue = {};
    for (const key in value) {
      newValue[key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = value[key];
    }
    return newValue;
  }
  return value;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think you mean *as they're received?

Comment: Oh maybe you did mean revived lulz

Comment: Can you please add more about how this works and how reviver works in general? By reading MDN docs for reviver I thought it wasn't possible too change the key.

Comment: @vibhor1997a - Did you review the code and the comments in it? You can't (sadly) change the key before hte object is created, but you can replace that object afterward with updated keys (which is what the above does).

Comment: Thanks for this, this works great except for arrays. When value is an array it should be returned unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
// Better use try-catch here
const parsedV = JSON.parse(v);
const parsed = Object.keys(parsedV).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[capitalize(key)] = parsedV[key];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: `Object.keys(JSON.parse(v))` instead of `Object.keys(v)`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought `v` was an object, I'll update my comment

Comment: *"No, but..."* Actually, you can, with a *reviver*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, I didn't know that. Good to know!